# How long og:image keep in Facebook cache?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I would like to know how much time are kept in cache images of the meta tag "og:image" ?
To be more precise: once the share posted on facebook (and so the image cached by Facebook), can I delete the image of my server?

Thank you

Comment: Facebook will re-scrape shared URLs from time to time, and users could also refresh the share attachment in their posts manually, so theoretically, you should keep them … _forever_. I don’t know how exactly the scraper reacts, when it simply gets a 404 for an image URL it could previously fetch without problems; I would _assume_ that it keeps the latest version it has cached then, but there is no guarantee I think.

Comment: @04FS Thank you for your answer. Indeed, if he uses the image in his cache in case he can not find it on the server it would be perfect. But I would like to be sure that it works like this ...